# WebAPI expected result on a Login process

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to WebAPI and would like to understand this. Let's assume a user is trying to Login and the login procedure should return a GUID "token" that is created and stored on the SQL Database ...or an "Email does not exist" or a "Email is still waiting for Confirmation".

Assuming the input is a LoginName and Password, what would be the APIController return and where is the right way to put the TOKEN on this case or those message?

QUESTION1:
What should be the APIController Method SIGNATURE?
   ...a class that has a couple of properties?
How should I return the Token to the client?
   ...inside the Header or as part of the result procedure?

QUESTION2:
What is the user has been blocked, shouldn't I return a HttpStatusCode.Forbidden or something similar? How can I do that if the signature is expecting a class return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a class that contains all of the result information you need.

```
public class ApiLoginResult
{
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expiration { get; set; }
}
```

Your method signature can define a return of type [HttpResponseMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.aspx) that contains a status code and data.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Login(string username, string password)
```

To return the ApiLoginResult message, you use the [HttpRequestMessage.CreateResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.createresponse%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method.

```
return Request.CreateResponse<ApiLoginResult>(statusCode, result);
```

Comment: So you always suggesting to ALWAYS return a HttpResponseMessage and if needed, pass the return object class as part of the ResponseMessage?

Comment: No, that is a matter of preference. I personally do it this way because it is cleaner to handle the status codes than throwing an HttpResponseException.